# Jupyter directories when in virtual environemnt

Tags: jupyter, conda, virtual-environment, jupyter-kernel

Where does jupyter store kernelspecs and other data, when running inside a virtual environment?

(I'm interested in `conda` environments, but knowing about other kinds of virtual envs would be interesting too).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it.

When inside a virtual environment, one can run

```
jupyter --paths
```

and one will see [jupyter locations](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html) (for the `jupyter` installed inside the currently active environment).

Something like:

```
config:
    /home/<user>/.jupyter
    /home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/<this-env>/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /home/<user>/.local/share/jupyter
    /home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/<this-env>/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /home/<user>/.local/share/jupyter/runtime
```

The directory where kernelspecs are would be `/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/<this-env>/share/jupyter/kernels`